# Can attackers send commands to/control infected air-gapped computers?

Tags: malware, air-gap

I've been reading up on malware that can bridge air gaps between computers, like GSMem, Funtenna, etc. In the papers and articles I've been reading, the researchers mostly talking about getting files and data out of air-gapped computers using parts and components of the computer not normally used for networkingor sending and receiving data.

My questions are:

1. How do attackers know which files to exfiltrate out of the air-gapped computer, since in the methods seem to only be able to get data out instead of also allowing the attacker to send communications TO the target computer?
2. Is it possible at all for attackers using these kinds of malware to send commands to or control air-gapped computers?

Comment: If the attackers cannot send data to the computers, then how does this malware get installed in the first place? 1 ) Because the attacker already has access to the machine or, 2) they can guess at what they want because the files are standard, a la Stuxnet. What they do not have access to is a network to exfiltrate files.

Comment: The function of the malware to send commands is entirely up to the type of malware you're talking about. "Is it possible?" Well, that's a matter for the papers you are reading.

Comment: @schroeder I meant to ask if there are any known ways for air-gapped computers to receive commands from attackers. The papers on these methods were proofs-of-concept detailing how data might be exfiltrated only.

Comment: @schroeder Since any user on a computer might have a myriad of files or data stored for even just the one user, in order for these attacks to be successful or even useful, they have to know which ones to exfiltrate. Does this mean that these are only useful for attackers with a fair amount of familiarity with not just the system being targeted but also the files stored there? What about any new files created or any new projects worked on at a later time?

Comment: Every paper I have read said the same thing. Usefulness depends on what the attacker is after. Consider Stuxnet. The attackers were after something specific. If the attacker wants to browse, then the attack method would have to allow bi-directional communication. If they know the file types, then it's trivial to look for PDFs, source code files, etc.

Comment: I remember reading some years ago about iMacs spreading malware via ultrasounds to other iMacs nearby by exploiting some vulnerability in the sound driver through the embedded microphone, but I can't manage to find the source. Maybe it was a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: @AlbertGomà I think you're thinking about (unproven) badBIOS, but it communicated through ultrasound, it didn't spread through it.

Comment: @Ginnungagap Most likely, according to Wikipedia it's been 7 years so far since it was published

Comment: Besides BitWhisper and acoustic covert channels, are there other known air-gap-bridging malware that  are bi-directional/allow the attacker to communicate with it over the air gap?